# Iterating over a dictionary and adding the values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict = {"a": 1,
        "e": 2,
        "i": 3,
        "o": 4,
        "u": 5}

s = "Welcome to Indonesia"

total = 0

for n in s:  

    if n in dict:

    # Add the total number of vowels. Answer - 22
```

I'm getting multiple errors and getting a bit confused. I'm trying to get the total value for vowels of the string. I decided to make a dict with the key being the vowels and the value being the value of the vowels.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name~

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please update your question with the exact error you are getting and your previous attempts to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Going in the opposite direction from @sebtheiler's answer, it can be done in a single statement:

```
vowel = {"a": 1,
         "e": 2,
         "i": 3,
         "o": 4,
         "u": 5}

s = "Welcome to Indonesia"

total = sum(vowel.get(ch, 0) for ch in s)
```

Perhaps not OP's original approach, but simple and readable. It generates all the vowel values by looping over the characters `ch` in `s`, using the default value of `0` if `ch` is not in `vowel` and summing the result as `total`.

If you want to catch uppercase vowels as well (like the `I` in `Indonesia`), this works:

```
total = sum(vowel.get(ch.lower(), 0) for ch in s)
```

Comment: It's cool to use *generator exp.* here.  but not sure OP miss this ```I```ndonesia?   *I* should be count?  +1

Comment: @DanielHao I wondered the same, but OP says they expect a result of `22`, which is omitting the `I`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) means we don't have to worry whether the value we're looking up is in the dictionary or not. If it's not, then the default `0` is returned.

```
vowels = {"a": 1,
          "e": 2,
          "i": 3,
          "o": 4,
          "u": 5}

s = "Welcome to Indonesia"

total = 0
for l in s:
    total += vowels.get(l, 0)

print(total)

# Output:
22
```

---

As for why you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name:

- I should be able to do:

```
>>> dict((('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')))
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

But if we've overwritten the built in `dict` with a variable, then this is the result, and other important places that use the built in `dict` may also now fail:

```
>>> dict((('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

[@BeRT2me's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73187942/10226703) is completely correct and more efficient; however, the following code is likely more understandable for a beginner and more in line with the original question:

```
dict = {"a": 1,
        "e": 2,
        "i": 3,
        "o": 4,
        "u": 5}

s = "Welcome to Indonesia"

total = 0

for n in s:  

    if n in dict:

        total += dict[n]

print(total)  # output: 22
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have fixed your issues your having with dictionaries. Given the goal is to 'get the total value for vowels of the string' I changed the values in your dictionary to 0 to initialize all the keys to 0. Also @BeRT2me comment is correct, 'dict' is a reserved word by python so making a unique variable is better.

```
dictionary_1 = {"a": 0,
                "e": 0,
                "i": 0,
                "o": 0,
                "u": 0}

s = "Welcome to Indonesia"

total = 0

for n in s:                      #Index through each letter 
                                 #in String 's'
    if n in dictionary_1:        #Check if letter is a key 
                                 #in the dictionary

        dictionary_1[n] += 1     #Increment the Value in the 
                                 #Dictionary by 1

print(dictionary_1)
```

The output from the print statement should be what you are looking for.

```
>> {'a': 1, 'e': 3, 'i': 1, 'o': 3, 'u': 0}
```